# How can I get the color of a pixel in a SharpDX Direct2D bitmap or render target?

Tags: sharpdx, direct2d

I am working on a simple drawing game and I need to get a Flood Fill algorithm working for a Paint Bucket tool.

I have the game running on WinForms at the moment which is extremely slow, but I have a working Flood Fill algorithm there, I could get the code to support SharpDX if I could get the color of a pixel (either from a `SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap` or from a `SharpDX.Direct2D1.RenderTarget`), but I can't find a way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the algorithm I am using accepts `System.Drawing.Bitmap` I only needed a way to capture a rendered frame onto one and then render the result, this is far from efficient but I've got a solution.

The solution uses PrintWindow from the WIN API.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);
```

This would probably only work if an embedded SharpDX control is used as capturing the control via handle won't do, but capturing a parent control, in this case the form, will return the desired image.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Width, Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
IntPtr hdcBitmap = g.GetHdc();

PrintWindow(Handle, hdcBitmap, 0);

g.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
g.Dispose();

// Crop the image to return only the part that we need, without control borders.
bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(SharpDXControl.Location.X + 1, SharpDXControl.Location.Y + 1, SharpDXControl.Width - 2, SharpDXControl.Height - 2), bmp.PixelFormat);
```

To draw the image, I created a new `SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap` instance and used the pixel data (bits) from the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` instance.

```
SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap dxbmp = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap(renderTarget, new SharpDX.Size2(bmpWidth, bmpHeight), new BitmapProperties(renderTarget.PixelFormat));
dxbmp.CopyFromMemory(bmpBits, bmpWidth * 4);
renderTarget.DrawBitmap(dxbmp, 1F, SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);
dxbmp.Dispose();
```

The algorithm I am using is a slightly modified version of the [Queue-Linear Flood Fill Algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16405/Queue-Linear-Flood-Fill-A-Fast-Flood-Fill-Algorith).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wishes to access pixel data in Direct2D...

Pixel data from a `Direct2D1.Bitmap1` is available to access colors.

The `Bitmap1` whose pixel data we wish to examine must be created using the `Direct2D1.BitmapOptions.CannotDraw` **AND** `Direct2D1.BitmapOptions.CpuRead` flags in the `Direct2D1.BitmapProperties1`, which is passed to the `Bitmap1` constructor.

The Direct2D documentation fails to mention that both flags are required.

The `Map` method of `Direct2D1.Bitmap1` returns a `Direct2D1.DataRectangle`.
This features two members: `DataPointer` and `Pitch`:

`DataPointer` is an `IntPtr` which points to the start of the memory occupied by the `Bitmap1` we're working on. Under GDI this is referred to as Scan0.

`Pitch` is the width of the `Bitmap1` expressed in bytes but includes padding (a 245x245 image yields a Pitch of 1024, suggesting byte alignment padding).

Here's some code which demonstrates the copying of data to and from a `Bitmap1` using `Marshal.Copy`:

```
' Create array of bytes for pixel data
m_Bytes = New Byte(m_Bitmap.PixelSize.Width * m_Bitmap.PixelSize.Height * 4 - 1) {}
' Lock the bitmap
m_DataRectangle = m_Bitmap.Map(MapOptions.Read)
' Copy pixel data to array
Marshal.Copy(m_DataRectangle.DataPointer, m_Bytes, 0, m_Bytes.Length)
' Copy pixel data array back to DataRectangle
Marshal.Copy(m_Bytes, 0, m_DataRectangle.DataPointer, m_Bytes.Length)
' Unlock bitmap
m_Bitmap.Unmap()
```